# Show alert dialog in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to display a simple `alert` when user clicks on my extension icon. I have tried this code :

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(
    alert(1)
);
```

Here is my `manifest` :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "sample",
  "description": "des",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
  ]
}
```

How do I show an alert `onClick` event ?

Comment: try `addListener(function() { alert(1) })`

Comment: @thg435 it did not work

Comment: "Didn't work?" Try giving it a punch.

Comment: @thg435 Punch :add to manifest "background": { "scripts": ["myScript.js"] }

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**updated:**

According the [browserAction documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/browserAction/) it is like:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() { 
  alert('Hello, World!'); 
})
```

and here is the [sample from Google (zip-file)](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/browserAction/set_icon_path.zip):

```
// Copyright (c) 2011 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

var min = 1;
var max = 5;
var current = min;

function updateIcon() {
  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"icon" + current + ".png"});
  current++;

  if (current > max)
    current = min;
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(updateIcon);
updateIcon();
```

Comment: Thanks for sample, I missed this line in manifest : `"background": { "scripts": ["myScript.js"] }`. Now it works.

Comment: where in the manifest does it go?  I get this: 
Manifest is not valid JSON.