# Lightbox Enable in Chrome App/Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, lightbox, google-chrome-app, kiosk-mode

I have created my first Chrome extension/app and found out that lightboxes do not function inside the app. I created the app from the [Google example kiosk app](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/SNP_E1B7A409D2D20FEBD817F2C8D0C73B52B9C6_4537340_en_v2). I'm only using webview in the app and have no other customizations. It just points to a link.

I want to use the app as an auto-launch Kiosk app on a Chromebox. Via [this website](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated) I found that 'alert' and 'confirm' are a disabled web feature on chrome web apps.

I am wondering if it is possible to enable alert and confirm in the Chrome app so that lightboxes will work when interacting with a website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely call alert box inside a chrome extension, just like you would in a normal javasript file as stated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19177216/show-alert-dialog-in-chrome-extension).

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(
    alert("Im an alert box triggered by Chrome Extension")
);
```

The link you provided suggests that you can create a custom popup/lightbox as a workaround. There's a complete tutorial [here](http://bryangentry.us/make-google-chrome-extension-launch-lightbox-user-clicks-context-menu/).
Happy coding! :)